# Getting IN parameters instead of row when retrieving ResultSet values

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to call a procedure from within my Java code. I first create a CallableStatement, then I associate my parameters with setString(x, "value").

My procedure SELECT the first result in a query. I can execute the procedure from SQL Server without a problem and get a result. From my Java code, I can't get anything except my IN parameters which are in my ResultSet...I don't understand how it is possible.

Here is the procedure creation script :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getTask] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @actionTypeParam nvarchar(50) = '', 
    @serverNameParam nvarchar(10) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @actionTypeParam, @serverNameParam
    SELECT TOP 1 actionId, actionType, partner, fileProt FROM dbo.Ordonnancement WHERE actionType = @actionTypeParam AND serverName = @serverNameParam AND actionState = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY actionRetry ASC, actionLocalDateTime ASC;
END
GO
```

And here is my Java code calling this procedure :

```
private static List<Action> getSyncTask() {
    List<Action> tasks = new ArrayList<Action>();

    Connection cnx;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        cnx = centralDb.getConnection();
        CallableStatement cstmt = cnx.prepareCall(PMASchedulerProcedures.GET_TASK);
        cstmt.setString(1, "sync");
        cstmt.setString(2, PMAUtils.getHostName());

        cstmt.execute();

        rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("[" + String.format("%-25s","Sync program")+"    ] : " 
                + "Cannot get SQL connection  : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Action action = new Action();
            action.setActionId(rs.getInt(1));
            action.setActionType(ActionType.fromName(rs.getString(2)));
            action.setPartner(rs.getString(3));
            action.setFileProt(rs.getString(4));
            tasks.add(action);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("[" + String.format("%-25s","Sync program")+"    ] : " 
                + "Cannot gather action informations  : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

I get the following result :

```
rs.getString(1) : sync
rs.getString(2) : PF11-40A
```

Which are the two parameters I set in my CallableStatement.

**If anyone has an idea about what happened here, I would be glad to hear it** :)

Comment: Also might be worth reading this. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Interesting, my company use this for each and every stored procedure. I'll ask them if they have a reason to do so. Thanks for the knowledge !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about Java, but your SQL stored procedure is returning two sets of results. I suspect the first SELECT, which is just getting the parameters that were passed in, was set up for some type of testing.  Try getting rid of the SELECT of the parameters like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getTask] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @actionTypeParam nvarchar(50) = '', 
    @serverNameParam nvarchar(10) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT TOP 1 actionId, actionType, partner, fileProt FROM dbo.Ordonnancement WHERE actionType = @actionTypeParam AND serverName = @serverNameParam AND actionState = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY actionRetry ASC, actionLocalDateTime ASC;
END
GO
```

Comment: You found the root of evil. I removed the first useless select and it worked. Thanks a lot !